# Adobe Flex to pure Action Script. How?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I have the following script which allows files to be upload through a PHP script into my web server but I was hoping to turn pseudo code into pure action script. Also, for some reason, my progress bar doesn't display the actual progress of the file upload.

**Here's the PHP code:**

```
<?php

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "./" . $fileName);

?>
```

**Here's the Adobe Flex code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="225" height="178" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import flash.net.FileReference;
        public var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
        public function uploadDialog(e:MouseEvent):void{
            errLabel.text="";
            var imgType:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images (*.GIF,*.JPG,*.PNG)","*.gif;*.jpg;*.png");
            var filterArray:Array=new Array(imgType);
            fileRef.browse(filterArray);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,fileSelect);
            fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,fileProgress);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,fileComplete);
        }

        public function fileSelect(e:Event):void{
            var fileURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("upload.php");
            try
            {
                //filepath.text=fileRef.name;
                fileRef.upload(fileURL);
            }
            catch (err:Error)
            { 
                errLabel.text="Unable to Upload File.....";
            }
        }

        public function fileProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            progBar.visible=true;
        }

        public function fileComplete(e:Event):void{

            errLabel.text="File Uploaded Sucessfully....."
            progBar.visible=false;

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


    <s:Label x="10" y="10" click="uploadDialog(event)" text="Upload ..."/>
    <mx:ProgressBar id="progBar" x="10" y="26"/>
    <s:Label id="errLabel" x="10" y="108" width="200" text="..."/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Why are you expecting your progress bar to change since you do nothing for that?

Comment: The code works, it seems there's an event listener for the ProgressEvent but I'm guessing PHP does not report file upload progression therefore Action Script sees only the beginning and the end. I guess I'll just throw a spinner instead.

Answer (score 0):

check this [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html#includeExamplesSummary): you have to set [`maximum`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html#maximum) and [`minimum`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html#minimum) properties and call [`setProgress`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html#setProgress%28%29) in your `fileProgress` function

there are two ways to turn flex code into pure as3: 
 * set `<keep-generated-actionscript>true</keep-generated-actionscript>` in flex-config.xml
 * rewrite your code without using mxml as a pure as3 project

Comment: It seems nothing is feeding the progress bar during the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for regarding progress bar update.

```
private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{ 
    pb.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal); 
}
```

Link for the solution.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf6.html